# Mostrar dato de la última actualización, si la hubo

Tags: python, django

en detalle.html me debe traer los datos solicitado pero cuando hago esto no me trae el dato de la ultima actualizacion.
detalles.html

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block Contenido %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col.lg-3">
            <h4>Registro ID #: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.id }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Nombre: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.nombre }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Apellidos: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.apellidos }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Cedula de identidad: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.ci }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Fecha de ingreso: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.creado }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Email: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.email }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Telefono: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.telefono }}</p></ul>            
            <h4>Documento: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.documento }}</p></ul>
            <h4>Ultima actualizacion: </h4>
                <ul><p>{{ object.fecha_actualizacion }}</p></ul>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <FORM NAME="buttonbar">
            <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Regresar" onClick="history.back()">
            </FORM>
        </center>
        <center>
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="imprimir" onclick="javascript:window.print()"> 
        </center>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Todo lo demás me lo muestra menos la informacion de mi ultima actualizacion.

Mis modelos:

```
from django.db import models

class Empleados(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField()
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
    upload_to="archivo/",
    null=True,
    blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)

class ActualizacionEmpleado(models.Model):
    empleado = models.OneToOneField('Empleados', null = False, blank = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

Debería traerme los datos que captura en mi base de datos, la cual revise y si guarda esta fecha.

Answer (score 1):

El campo `fecha_actualizacion` no es parte del modelo `Empleados`, lo tiene que hacer a través de la relación que has definido con `ActualizacionEmpleado`· Por lo tanto, deberías mostrarlo de esta forma:

```
<p>{{ object.actualizacionempleado.fecha_actualizacion }}</p>
```

Recuerda que en este caso `object` es el objeto para `Empleado` y `object.fecha_actualizacion` no existe según la definición de tus modelos.

Comment: hice lo que me comentaste pero aun no me trae la fecha de la ultima actualizacion, si la hubo

Answer (score 0):

Cómo el atributo actualizarempleado  no es en el modelo Empleado no puedes acceder directamente desde la plantilla, tendrás que pasar por contexto otro objeto de Actualizarempleado que deseas.

Por ejemplo puedes acceder a atributos de empleado desde actualizarempleado así:

```
{{ actualizacionempleado.empleado.nombre }}
```

Porque empleado es atributo de Actualizarempleado

Pero no puedes acceder a un atributo de Actualizarempleado desde empleado así:

```
 # esto no te devolverá ningún valor
 {{ empleado.actualizacionempleado.fecha_actualizacion }}
```

Porque no es atributo de empleado.

Esto solo ocurre en las plantillas, en las vistas y demás esto si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal yo te sugiero:

1. Que elimines el modelo ActualizacionEmpleado
2. Y en el modelo Empleados agregue campo  `fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` ya que auto_now se ejecuta cada vez que sea llamada la instancia esto quiere decir que cada vez que realices cambio sobre el modelo este campo almacenara el momento en el que aplicas el cambio ([*auto_now*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now))

y bueno así mejoras algo de sintaxis.